# Journey Builder API Event Entry Internal Server Error

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, journeybuilder, dataextensions

I created a simple journey to test API events. It looks like this:

[image: API Event Triggered Journey]

As you can see it's a very simple journey. It's supposed to be triggered by an API call, send an email and exit.

It uses a sendable filtered data extension with 5 contacts as its source.

I call the APIs like so:

```json
{
    "ContactKey": "contactkey",
    "EventDefinitionKey": "APIEvent-58eb5c58-46aa-*********",
    "Data": {
        "email address": "email@address.com",
        "userid": "userid"
    }
}
```

However I get an internal server error as a response:

```json
{
    "message": "Internal Server Error",
    "errorcode": 0,
    "documentation": "https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/error-handling.htm"
}
```

Any idea why this might be?

---

If I don't include the userid and email address attributes in data, I get the following response:

```json
{
    "message": "Required Event Data fields are missing: email address, userid",
    "errorcode": 30000,
    "documentation": ""
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is

> It uses a sendable filtered data extension with 5 contacts as its source.

The DE can not be a filtered data extension. The api call does an insert into the entry source DE and also an injection into the journey. If you have selected a filtered DE it is unable to insert a record into the DE.

Create a new DE to be used as your entry source.

Answer (score 0):

I also had faced the similar issue and I was able to resolve it by "removing the SCOPE", from the Access token request.

Example: If we use the scope as below, we would be able to only read/write email.NOT read Journey, send email etc etc...

```
 {
"grant_type": "client_credentials",
"client_id": "7a9j47upktedde30uedl822p",
"client_secret": "1955278925675241571",
"scope": "email_read email_write",
"account_id": "12345"
}
```