# Entry Customer Journey via API entry event

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, journeybuilder

In Marketing Cloud, I have created a Customer Journey with an API event as entry source and a corresponding (sendable) Data Extension. When I make the request to the API with Postman, I only get a `403 Forbidden` response with the following message:

```
"Insufficient privileges to complete this action"
```

My request body looks as follows, according to [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postEvent.htm) and [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/179400/how-to-fire-journey-api-entry-event-through-ampscript) posts:

```
Host: https://MY_SUBDOMAIN.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
POST /interaction/v1/events
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer MY_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN

{
    "ContactKey": "abc123",
    "EventDefinitionKey":"MY_API_EVENTKEY",
    "EstablishContactKey": true,
    "Data": {
        "ContactKey":"abc123",
        "EventDefinitionKey":"MY_API_EVENTKEY",
        "DataExtensionColumn1": "Value1",
        "DataExtensionColumn2": "Value2" }
}
```

Can anybody give me a hint on what I am missing? The Installed Package with API Integration has Read/Write permissions on both Data Extensions and Customer Journeys (and also Execute for Customer Journeys).

Comment: Have you ensured your app (that you connect via) has the required scope to make the request? That's likely what it is.

Comment: What scope is required by the app? Right now it has an API Integration with a scope of Journeys (Read/Write/Execute) and Data Extensions (Read/Write).

Comment: Was permission given to Journeys in your Installed Package at a point after the package was created?  I have found in the past that permissions cannot be changed/updated once the package is created.  I am unsure if this has changed in the past couple years.  Can you try creating a new installed package, setting the proper permissions at the time of creation, then attempting to use it's credentials for OAuth?

Comment: Tried it just now, but still the same result unfortunately...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm almost positive that you're being affected by a recent SFMC security upgrade.

What is going on: SFMC had recently discovered that some REST routes were not following the least access principle in regards to usage, meaning some users could occasionally do more using a route that their access would specifically have allowed.

Here is how to find out what you're missing: 
 Go to [the SFMC developer documentation on the subject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/resolve-rest-permissions-report.htm) and run the reports.  It will show what you're trying to hit, and where you need to add access.  Of course, you don't HAVE to add that access... you may not want some of those users to access those things.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, my installed package does not appear in the report and the error still comes up... I tried with another package without OAuth and then receive [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/265592/journey-builder-api-event-entry-internal-server-error) error, although I don't use a Filtered Data Extension

Comment: I ran the report again after one week and today it told me to adapt the permissions for "Email" and "List and Subscribers". I gave Email Read access and List/Subscribers Read/Write access and now it seems to work... Thanks!